# Executing C++ code from python

Tags: python, c++, file, directory

I am a beginner to python, and I have no idea if this seems to be a doable thing.

I have a simple loop in python that gives me all the files in the current directory. 
What I want to do is to execute a C++ code I wrote before on all those files in the directory from python

The proposed python loop should be something like this

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    print filename
    (Execute the code.cpp on each file with each iteration)
```

Is there any chance to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running c++ code from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113704/running-c-code-from-python)

Comment: Did you search SO for your topic? There are few posts that discusses executing C++ code in python. Here is one. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113704/running-c-code-from-python  and

Comment: @Anil_M Thank you for the link. I did search for related questions but didn't find that one. 
I am reading it now and still can not feel that I found and answer to my question.

Comment: Is your C++ code in a main program or as a shared object/DLL ?

Comment: @cdarke it is in a main program

Comment: OK, 2 more questions.  How do you pass the filename to the main program - command-line `*argv[]` or `cin` or some other way?  Which version of python are you using?  The solution will be to use the `subprocess` module, if you are on 3.5, `subprocess.run()`.

Comment: @cdarke I pass the filename by *argv[] and I am using python 2.7

Comment: OK, I'll post a simple solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fairly easy to execute an external program from Python - regardless of the language:

```
import os
import subprocess

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):   
    print filename
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["./myprog", filename])
    proc.wait()
```

The list used for arguments is platform specific, but it should work OK.  You should alter `"./myprog"` to your own program (it doesn't have to be in the current directory, it will use the PATH environment variable to find it).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. 
I have 2 questions as well if you don't mind.
1st, this is limited to windows I guess? (cause your wrote ./myprog)
2nd, I forgot to mention that my program takes, in addition to the filename, 4 another arguments and do some computation on them. So how could I include the arguments in this case?
could it be something like 
 proc = subprocess.Popen(["./myprog", filename], arg1, arg2,...)?

Comment: No, that's not Windows specific, which OS are you using?  To add other arguments, add them to the list:  `subprocess.Popen(["./myprog", filename, arg1, arg2],...)`.  You might be able to get away with a string for the argument list instead, but usually a list is simpler.

Comment: I just tried it on MAC and it worked with arguments and everything went fine! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great!  Next time you ask here bear in mind the questions I had to ask.   Your mention of C++ made people think you wanted to call C++ from Python *in the same process*.  You can do that using the Python API, although it is rather more complex than creating a child process.  In this case the language was actually irrelevant.